# How do I run tests using maven if I have multiple test classes with multiple tests in them which are prioritized?

Tags: java, maven, web-testing

I have 6 test classes, in each I have around 5 tests, which are prioritized.
When I run the test suit using maven, the test classes are combined somehow. 
While the tests are not finished from a test class, another one starts, and fails my tests.
Is there a way, to run 1 test class with all of its tests first, and to run the second class after the first one is finished and so on?
Note: I run the test using a mvn command in Terminal.

Comment: your tests should not affect each others outcome, they should clean up after themselves.

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you have so far?

Comment: https://github.com/ghsukumar/SFDC_Best_Practices/wiki/F.I.R.S.T-Principles-of-Unit-Testing

Comment: Sorry, but I can't share the code. Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I have around 5 tests, which are prioritized*

Probably you are using **TestNG**, having something like this for every test method:

```
@Test( priority = 1 )
```

If this is the case, you should add this as a tag because it's quite relevant.

> *the test classes are combined somehow*

Probably you run them in **parallel**.

> *Is there a way, to run 1 test class with all of its tests first, and to run the second class after the first one is finished and so on*

Yes. Run the classes **sequentially**!

Find the XML file like **testng.xml** where you defined the test suite. It should contain something like this:

```
<suite name="YourSuite" parallel="classes" thread-count="6">
```

Remove `parallel="classes" thread-count="6"` to achieve what you described above.

See [TestNG - parallel tests](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests) for other details.

Answer (score 1):

Each class should have its own set-up and tear-down mechanism, so that the tests of different test classes are completely independent of each other. If several tests use a common resource that is expensive, put these tests together in one class and create the resource in the set-up method.

If you absolutely need to call some methods in a given order, you have write a test method which calls these methods (in the specified order). But you should try to avoid this as much as possible.

Comment: @Doraryn: The usual way to "thank" on StackOverflow is to upvote or to accept an answer. I hope my answer does help you a bit in your problem.

Comment: thank you for the info, but I can't upvote :) that's why I wrote a thank you message (I'm pretty new around here, asking questions)

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer to your question by clicking on the icon next to the answer.